# Hibernate Criteria Existing Third Table

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I'm just trying to set some restrictions for my criteria.
The situation is as follows:

```
Relation account
id, name, first name

Relation account2project
account.id, project.id

Relation project
id, title
```

There is a many-to-many connection between those relations. Now I want to restrict as follows:

```
sess.createCriteria(account.class).
add(Restrictions.like("%" + account.getProject() + "%"));
```

What shoud return are only those accounts which have a project with a certain title.
I tried setting aliases, but I can't really figure out what to type in here.
Could any of you help me real quick!

Thanks Max

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for criteria queries? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: Well yeah, but in these cases there is always a reference-attribute within the main-relation itself. There's no example with a third relation in between them. When I try to set an alias on "account" using projects I'm getting a "property cannot be found", which makes sense, because there is no property project in accounts. But how would I access the "bridge"-table in between those to relations from within account.class

Comment: Can you share the class definitions please? Atleast the actual properties in them.

Comment: Between Account and Project? Yeah

Accounts: https://www.refheap.com/d0d05c5c159998fa17834162a
Project; https://www.refheap.com/6539ea74d440394e27d35aa41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using the following code:

```
sess.createCriteria(account.class)
  .createCriteria("assignedProjects")
    .add(Restrictions.like("title","%someTitle%"));
```

Here, you nest another `Criteria` for the `assignedProjects` property and add the 'like' restriction on it.